# didFailToReceiveAdWithError function of iad is not working

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, iad

I implemented both iAd and AdMob to my project. The structure is if an error comes from iAd server, the app going to show Admob banner or interstitial according to error ad type. Interstitial works fine. But not banners. I used the function shown below and I selected the iAd fill rate to 0% in developer setting of simulator. But it's not writing "WORKED" to console and it's not showing iAd Banner ad(as expected). How can I solve this problem?

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("WORKED")

    }
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works fine for me?

Comment: Edit your question to include all of your `ADBannerView` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not setting your `ADBannerView`'s `delegate` properly. Your code should look similar to this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate { // Include the delegate for our ADBannerView
```

And then wherever you are setting up your `ADBannerView` you need to set its `delegate`. For example:

```
yourAdBannerView.delegate = self
```

You will probably want to `print` your `error` also so you know why it has failed. For example:

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your plain response. I think I wrote something wrong. I used another solution and pasted the link above. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386514/app-approved-but-no-admob-ads-appearing/30413810#30413810

Comment: @twigofa I've updated [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30413810/2108547) answer to include the code I mention here.