# Prioritizing iAd over adMob SpriteKit / Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob, iad

I integrated both iAd and adMob into my game, with adMob code only running when iAd fails to load. If the iAd does not fail loading the first ad, it works fine. Admob works like it should when iAd fails to load. However, when iAd fails but then loads the next ad, the adMob banner still exists and the iAd is not shown. How do I make it so that iAd loads even when adMob already is. Also, the iAd banner loads fine after failing to load when the adMob code is commented out. On an unrelated note, how do change the fill rate of adMob ads in the simulator? Thanks. This is my code in my GameViewController (iAd is called in gameScene):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var SH = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()
var googleBannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    /*  var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0)
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd) */

    UIiAd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView":UIiAd]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    UIiAd.delegate = nil
    UIiAd.removeFromSuperview()
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.alpha = 1 // Fade in the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    println("iAd work")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1)
    UIiAd.alpha = 0
    UIView.commitAnimations()

    googleBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape)
    googleBannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    googleBannerView.rootViewController = self
    var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    googleBannerView.loadRequest(request)

    googleBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.bounds.height - googleBannerView.frame.size.height, googleBannerView.frame.size.width, googleBannerView.frame.size.height)

    self.view.addSubview(googleBannerView!)

    println("iAd fail")
}

func showBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = false
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH - BV, 2048, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}

func hideBannerAd() {
    UIiAd.hidden = true
    var BV = UIiAd.bounds.height

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1) // Time it takes the animation to complete
    UIiAd.frame = CGRectMake(0, SH + BV, 0, 0) // End position of the animation
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.UIiAd.hidden = true
    self.UIiAd.alpha = 0

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "hideBannerAd", name: "hideadsID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showBannerAd", name: "showadsID", object: nil)

    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1356))
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    println("Clicked")
    //  let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
    //  skView.scene!.paused = true
    return true
}
/*    func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
let skView: SKView = self.view as! SKView
skView.scene!.paused = false
} */

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're not hiding your AdMob banner when iAd receives an ad in your `bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!)`. So, your iAd banner is actually being displayed behind your AdMob banner.

Alternatively, you could create both your iAd and AdMob banners once in your `viewDidLoad` and hide or show them depending on if iAd receives an ad or not. Your iAd delegate methods would end up looking similar to this:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    // Show iAd
    UIiAd.alpha = 1.0
    // Hide AdMob
    googleBannerView.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    // Hide iAd
    UIiAd.alpha = 0.0
    // Show AdMob
    googleBannerView.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30413810/2108547) for a complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I made an ad helper for swift, why don't you check it out, it does exactly what you want. It was primarily made for SpriteKit.
https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-iAds-and-AdMob-Helper